# Why when I uncommenting toString it writes null?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List db = new ArrayList();

        ShopDatabase sb = new ShopDatabase(db);
        sb.addEntry(new ProductEntry("film", 30, 400));
        sb.addEntry(new CashierEntry("Kate", "Smith", 23, 600));
        sb.addEntry(new ManagerEntry("Jack", "Simpson", 1, 700));
        sb.addEntry(new ProductEntry("soap", 18, 3));
        sb.addEntry(new ManagerEntry("Helen", "Jones", 60, 650));
        sb.addEntry(new CashierEntry("Jane", "Tomson", 15, 900));
        sb.addEntry(new ProductEntry("shampoo", 25, 5));
        sb.addEntry(new CashierEntry("Bill", "Black", 59, 300));
        Collections.sort(db);
        Iterator itr = db.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry element = (Entry) itr.next();
            System.out.println(element + "\n");
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Entry implements Comparable {

    public String name;
    public int id;

    public Entry(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object entry) {
        Entry temp = (Entry) entry;
        int difference = this.id - temp.id;
        return difference;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.id + " " + this.name;
    }
}



public class People extends Entry {

    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private int id;
    private int salary;

    public People(String name, String familyName, int id, int salary) {
        super(name, id);
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    /*
     * public String toString() { return this.id + " " + this.name + " " +
     * this.familyName + " " + this.salary; } /*public int compareTo(Object
     * entry) { Entry temp = (Entry) entry; int difference = this.id - temp.id;
     * return difference;
     * 
     * }
     */

}


public class ProductEntry extends Entry {

    public String name;
    public int id;
    public int stock;

    public ProductEntry(String name, int id, int stock) {
        super(name, id);
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    /*
     * public String toString() { return this.id + " " + this.name + " " +
     * this.stock; } /*public int compareTo(Object entry) { Entry temp = (Entry)
     * entry; int difference = this.id - temp.id; return difference;
     * 
     * }
     */
}



public class ManagerEntry extends People {

    public String name;
    public String familyName;
    public int id;
    public int salary;

    public ManagerEntry(String name, String familyName, int id, int salary) {
        super(name, familyName, id, salary);
    }
}



public class CashierEntry extends People {

    public String name;
    public String familyName;
    public int id;
    public int salary;

    public CashierEntry(String name, String familyName, int id, int salary) {
        super(name, familyName, id, salary);
    }

    /*
     * public String toString() { return this.id + " " + this.name + " " +
     * this.familyName + " " + this.salary; }
     */
}
```

Can anyone please help when I have code like this the output is

```
1 Jack

15 Jane

18 soap

23 Kate

25 shampoo

30 film

59 Bill

60 Helen
```

but if I uncommenting toString in People and ProductEntry the output is

```
0 null Simpson 700

0 null Tomson 900

0 null 3

0 null Smith 600

0 null 5

0 null 400

0 null Black 300

0 null Jones 650
```

why name and id is becomming null ???? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is name and id are null.

When you retrieve `this.id`, it returns the value of this classes (ProductEntry) member variable rather than its super class (which is what you want in this case).  If these member variables weren't defined in ProductEntry, a call to this.id would retrieve the id from the super class, in this case Entry.  This is known as [Variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

You can solve the problem in two possible ways.  The first is to simply remove name and id member variables from the sub classes of Entry.  This will mean `this.id` will access the member variable of `Entry` rather than its sub class `ProductEntry`.  The other option is to simply assign these in the constructor, but as you already storing these values in the super class, I don't think this is the best approach.

In the spirit of encapsulation you also may want to consider making your member variables private (only accessible by the class there defined in), or protected (accessible by the class its defined in and its sub types).

Answer (score 5):

You're [shadowing (JLS 6.3.1)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1) `name` and `id`: you set the superclass properties, but you print `Person`s, which are never set. The point of OOP is specifically *not* to re-implement shared behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple fields called `name`. The one in `People` **shadows** the one in `Entry`, and so on.

What happens is that the constructor sets the base class's `name`, and `toString()` prints out the derived class's `name` (which has never been initialized and is therefore `null`).

Same for `id`.

Simply remove `name` and `id` from `People` and `ProductEntry`, and it'll behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Because in `People` you never set the member variables. You only pass `name` and `id` to the super class. And in `toString()` you are using the variables of `People` and not from the super class. You are *shadowing* them

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple name,id,... variables in your classes. the constructor sets those in people the tostring uses those in the subclass which are null. remove the public variable declarations from the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

In `People` you don't set variables for name, and id, you send them to the super class. Therefore they don't exist in your People class, and when you try to print them you end up "shadowing" them.

Answer (score 0):

The `this.name` in People accesses the field `name` local to that class. You never assign a value to that field (but instead to the same field in Entry), so it will return `null` always.

Answer (score 0):

ProductEntry and People both have members named "name" in the subclass.  Remove this subclass member, and it should work as you expect.

Basically what's happening is that the subclass member is hiding the superclass member, but during initialization, you're delegating to the superclass, so it initializes the now hidden Entity.name member, which isn't visible from Person and ProductEntry anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing the variables `name` and `id` with other fields named `name`, and `id`, and so the compiler is getting confused as to what to refer to (the superclass versions, or the versions from `Person`, which are never defined). Follow @aix's and @Dave Newton's advice and you'll be good to go.